# If you are using a Apple Watch, do you first need to open the Health App to sync data and then open your own healthkit app to get the latest data?

Tags: ios, healthkit

The issue is my App doesnt get the latest steps data unless I go inside the Health App first and then goto my App. Does the Apple watch not sync with Apple Health automatically or is their a workaround in Healthkit API which forces a sync?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HealthKit data syncs to your phone from Apple Watch periodically in the background. Additionally, launching the Health app, Activity app, or any app with a live HKHealthStore will also trigger a sync. There is no programmatic way to trigger a sync, though.

Comment: Thanks Allan. Yeah I saw its getting synched automatically in like 1-2 hours.  I hope they add a way for the user to select the sync interval.